# aspnet_user table for storing customer information

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

When regsitering in my site (ASP.Net MVC application), the users get inserted into the aspnet_users table. Since its a shopping site, I would want the users to have a customer id and all their details provided by them at registration in this Customer table as well. How do I link these 2 tables? Is it recommended to use the aspnet_user's UserId(Guid) in the application for other business processes.

Also, I would like to know when should a new record be inserted into the customers table. 
I mean, when should a new customer be created. I guess its not good to create a record as ans when users are registered? Here, I want to know whats the norm? I felt it would be better to add it when a user adds an item to the shopping cart. Pls guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the UserId field into your customer table and then make a foreign key relationship back to the UserId in the aspnet_users table if you want to enforce relational integrity.

I'm not sure what you mean about when to insert the customer record.  As long as you insert it after you have created the user (so that you have the user ID), you should be fine.  It can happen in the same postback.

I'm not sure how you are saving the user.  As in are you using one of the built-in ASP.Net controls or making the call manually?

If you are using the Membership provider as it sounds like you are, you can save the member using:

```
var user = Membership.CreateUser;
Guid userKey = user.ProviderUserKey;
//Populate your customer object.
//now use whatever EF/ADO/etc... to save your customer record.
```

Comment: Yes, I am using the Membership provider for saving the values. Yes, you have understood my second question correctly. I wanted to know when to add the new record to customer i.e, promoting a user to a customer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is that answer helpful to you or are you trying to figure out something else?